# how to create a list of excel sheets name that only lie between two specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

i successfully posted all sheets names in one list through this VB code within the sheet name DEFINITIONS, but actually i need this list to include only the sheets between "START PROJECTS" and "END PROJECTS" sheets and dont list the remaining sheets in the list,this is the basic code i uesed

```
Sub GetListOfAllSheets()

   Dim w As Worksheet

   Dim i As Integer

   i = 2

   Sheets("DEFINITIONS").Range("W:W").Clear
   For Each w In Worksheets
       Sheets("DEFINITIONS").Cells(i, 16) = w.Name
       i = i + 1
       
       exception = False
   Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: You tagged VB.net, are you sure it's not VBA? This code snippet could easily work in VBA...

Comment: Also, the variable ‘exception’ is not declared, so this is not a working VB.net code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a status flag to determine if you are between the sheets of interest like in this example:

```
Sub GetListOfAllSheets()
    flag = False

    For Each w In Worksheets
        If w.Name = "START PROJECTS" Then
            flag = True
        End If
        
        If flag Then
            MsgBox (w.Name)
        End If
        
        If w.Name = "END PROJECTS" Then
            flag = False
        End If
    Next w
End Sub
```